# Rails model attribute is nil in custom validator method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a polymorphic table, and I want to be able to verify that the entity id provided on *create* does in fact reference an existing object. I wrote a custom validator to do just this, which is invoked when I call `find_or_create_by`. However, the attributes that I am performing validation on are nil in the validation method.

```
  validate :validate_id, on: :create
...

  def validate_id
    klass = Object.const_get(entity_type)

    return if klass.exists?(entity_id)

    errors.add(:entity_id, 'is invalid')
  end
```

`entity_type` and `entity_id` are both model members, and are passed as args to `find_or_create_by`. I don't understand why they are nil in the validation method.

Comment: Why do you believe them to be `nil`? How are you confirm that they were set in the first place? Additionally as I understand it `belongs_to` relationships are validated by default now (As of Rails 5). Is this not the case in your Application?

Answer (score 0):

The reason those values don't hold anything in your method is because they are only scoped to that method, and that method does not take them in as arguments. The best way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to write a *proper* custom validator that inherits from `ActiveModel::EachValidator` and implements the `validate_each(record, attribute, value)` method.

Although you can get away with a `validates_each` block:

```
validates_each :entity_id do |record, attr, value|
  return if Entity.exists?(value)
  errors.add(attr, 'is invalid')
end
```

However...

Why not just use a normal inclusion validator?
Since I'm on Rails 4.2 right now this is how I do it when `Entity` record counts are low enough for it not to cause performance issues.
(I'd use a better error message, but using yours for simplicity.)

```
  validates :entity_id,
            inclusion: { in:      proc { Entity.all.pluck(:id) },
                         message: 'is invalid' }
```

---

Edit: I see now the issue is that your polymorphic entity means the examples above won't work without some tweaking since `Entity` could be either of two models `EntityOne` or `EntityTwo`. You could easily check if either of them contain the ID in question like this:

```
validates_each :entity_id do |record, attr, value|
  return if EntityOne.exists?(value) || EntityTwo.exists?(value)
  errors.add(attr, 'is invalid')
end
```

Or

```
  validates :entity_id,
            inclusion: { in:      proc { EntityOne.all.pluck(:id) + EntityTwo.all.pluck(:id) },
                         message: 'is invalid' }
```

But this isn't a great validation since there are invalid situations passed through as valid.

You might have to resort to a *proper* custom validator that inherits from `ActiveModel::Validator` and implements the `validate(record)` method which also accepts `options` where you can pass in the type of entity expected. It would look like this:

```
# Inside the model:
validates_with(EntityIdValidator, expected_entity: entity_type)



#The custom validator:
class EntityIdValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)
    expected_entity = options[:expected_entity]
    return if expected_entity.exists?(record.entity_id)

    record.errors.add(:entity_id, 'is invalid')
  end
end
```